# How to Model get a value from URL or etc

Tags: python, django

I have 2 Model with Foreign Key

First model is "Reporter"
Second model is "Article"

My Article Add page url is : IP:8000/<**Reporter-ID**>/add_article/

My Article Model like that:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want on my template, user can be select **headline** and **pub_date** ,

but **reporter** fill automaticly from URL or etc. How can I do this?

My view;

```
def addArticle(request,id):
    reporter = get_object_or_404(Reporter,id=id)
    form=AddArticle(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('ayar')

    context = {"form":form,"reporter":reporter}
    return render(request, "add-article.html", context)
```

My Urls:

```
    path('add-article/<int:id>/',addArticle,name="addArticle"),
```

I new on Django and my english level is low. I wish you understand me

Comment: Can you show be your views?

Comment: @SancaKembang updated question

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at grabbing the url as a parameter and passing that to your 'view'.

Your app should have a urls.py with a list of url_patterns.  An entry in this list might be something like this (I've added an 'r' before the reporter ID otherwise this path will match any int - just a choice.)

`# urls.py
url_patterns = [
 path('r<int:r_id>/add_article/', views.Add_article.as_view(), name='add_article'),
]`

That 'r' will capture strings like r12, split them into `r` and `12` and then cast the '12' to an int.

Then in your view you find the matching reporter (hopefully there is one):

`reporter = Reporters.objects.get(id=r_id)`

You can create the Article with:
`article = Article(content=content, reporter=reporter)`

Answer (score 0):

By following your views, I think you just need little change;

```
if form.is_valid():
    article = form.save(commit=False)
    article.reporter = reporter        # here
    article.save()
    form.save()

    return redirect('ayar')
```